# Is there a way to determine the number of values you want to push in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to add the same vec4 colors into an already existing array but I want to add n number of instances of the same color. For example, I created an array that holds 36 values of the same color:

```
var colours = new Array(36).fill(vec4( 0.01,0.43,0.79,1.0 ));
```

Now,I want to add another color value 36 times into the same existing array.

```
colours.push(vec4( 0.01,0.43,0.79,1.0 ));
```

This just inserts one instance of the value I want, but I want to add 36 of them. Instead of writing multiple push lines, is there a way to push 36 values all together?

Comment: a for loop which runs 36 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a for loop

```
for (var i=0; i<36;i++){
   colours.push(vec4( 0.01,0.43,0.79,1.0 ));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `...` syntax to spread the new array into multiple arguments.

```
colours.push(...new Array(36).fill(vec4( 0.01,0.43,0.79,1.0 )))
```

Or use the `concat()` method:

```
colours = colours.concat(new Array(36).fill(vec4( 0.01,0.43,0.79,1.0 )));
```

The second method creates a new array rather than pushing into the existing array.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add while you can do this

```
colours.push(...new Array(36).fill(vec4( 0.01,0.43,0.79,1.0 )))
```

In both cases, the origial

```
var colours = new Array(36).fill(vec4( 0.01,0.43,0.79,1.0 ));
```

And the code adding 36 more, the are not adding 36 vec4s. They are adding 1 vec4 36 times.

Example:

```js
const vec4 = (...args) => args;

const colours = new Array(4).fill(vec4(1, 2, 3, 4));

console.log(colours.flat().join(','));

colours[0][0] = 789;

console.log(colours.flat().join(','));
```